# How to sort array by multiple attributes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have list of user profiles. I need to sort the user profile based on following criteria as shown below:

```
profile_claimed(boolean) -> profile_complete_status(integer) -> No_of_friends(integer)
```

code:

```
user_profiles.sort { |x| [x.claim ? 0 : 1, x.complete_profile_status, x.no_of_friends] }
```

How to sort the user profile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797507/sort-a-list-with-multiple-conditions-ruby-on-rails?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
user_profiles.sort_by do |x| 
  [(x.claim ? 0 : 1), x.complete_profile_status, x.no_of_friends]
end
```

Also, it is worth noting that `sort_by` is usually faster than `sort` because it caches the result of the comparison operation, which in this case is

```
(x.claim ? 0 : 1), x.complete_profile_status, x.no_of_friends
```

and does not recalculate the values for each comparison between two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sort` method with block:

```
ary.sort do |x,y|
  if x > y
    1
  elsif x < y
    -1
  else
    0
  end
end
```

Just make sure to return `+1` when `x` follows `y`, `-1` when `y` follows `x`, or `0` when they are equal.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: While `sort` is the basic building block for sorting, it often falls down badly when the values being sorted have to be computed or dug out of a structure or object. Instead, use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), which uses a [Schwarzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), resulting in major speed improvements.